# How to retrieve multiple data from rows which are in different columns of each row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to retrieve some data from a particular row but I don't know in which column the data is.
eg.

```
       col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
row1   A      B    C     D    E    F
row2   H      B    G     E    I    J
```

now I need data B and G, it is in both row1 and row2 and I need to get values in out like this  B    C     D    E while running the command.

Most probably I was enabled to think what good code should I write for it.

expected output

```
B C D E    from row1
B G E      from row2
```

[image]

this is the actual data
Where i need to call data between GTB and Sion 
There are two rows which provide GTB and SION
But they both are in different columns

```
SELECT __________  
FROM `busroute` 
WHERE 'GTB' IN (Source,Stop2,Stop3,Stop4,Stop5,Stop6,Stop7,Stop8,Stop9,Destination)
AND 'Wadala' IN  (Source,Stop2,Stop3,Stop4,Stop5,Stop6,Stop7,Stop8,Stop9,Destination);
```

OUTPUT SHOULD BE :

```
ROW1   -   Sion Koliwada GTB
ROW2   -    Sion SionCircle Koliwada GTB
```

Comment: What's the logic determining the specific output you are expecting?

Comment: G is not in row 1.  It is always harder for volunteers when you explain your data in unrealistic terms.  Your question is Unclear and doesn't show any effort.

Comment: Do you need to exclude rows where `Wadal` comes before `GTB` (runs in opposite direction)?  ...seems logical/necessary to me.

Comment: yes, but i only want data from a specific position which I have mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the optimized way, but you can get your answer as follow:

- Here the sequence matters, you have to consider these two variables as source and destination.
- Here `Sion` is a source and `GTB` is a destination. If you have different then replace source value with all values of `Sion` and destination value with all values of `GTB`.
- `--` sign is used to distinguish between two stations, if one station has substring which represents another station. Like `Sion Circle` has `Sion` as substring which represents another station.

**Logic**:

- Both stations should be present for any route for any destinations. So we have used `WHERE` clause for both inputs with `IN` operator for all `stops`.
- `CONCAT_WS('--', '--', Source,Stop2,Stop3,Stop4,...,Destination, '--')` It create a list of all station separated by `--` and also adds `--` at both ends. e.g. `--A--B--C--D--`.
- Why `--` are added, so we can do a full exact search for a station so it can't overlap with other stations.

```
Example: if I have to search 'Sion' then search will be `--Sion--`

 --Sion--Sion Circle--BC   : Return true
 --Sion Circle--BC--AKDKJ--: return false, simple search would have return true.
```

- `SUBSTRING_INDEX` is used to remove unnecessary left and right part of the route based on source or destination
- Added source and destination to the newly generated route again to show the complete route.
- Finally remove all `--` which were added for calculation purpose.

**Query**:

```
SELECT
    b.RouteID,
    b.BusNo,
    REPLACE(CONCAT_WS(' ', 'Sion', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT_WS('--', '--', Source,Stop2,Stop3,Stop4,Stop5,Stop6,Stop7,Stop8,Stop9,Destination, '--'), '--Sion--', -1), '--GTB--', 1),'GTB'),'--', ' ') as route
FROM busroute b
WHERE 'GTB' IN (Source,Stop2,Stop3,Stop4,Stop5,Stop6,Stop7,Stop8,Stop9,Destination)
AND 'Sion' IN  (Source,Stop2,Stop3,Stop4,Stop5,Stop6,Stop7,Stop8,Stop9,Destination);
```

Comment: actually Sion and SionCircle are two different locations.

Comment: Yup that what I have considered. Does this query giving result as expected or not?

Comment: I have make sure that if you search for `Sion` it should match with `Sion` only not with `Sion Circle`.  That what i've mentioned `-- sign is used to distinguish between two stations`